# Angular - APP_INITIALIZER - Promise vs Observable

Tags: angular, typescript

I have the application based on Angular v4. The scenario is simple - I need to load some settings from the server before the app starts. To do so, I use the `APP_INITIALIZER`:

```
{
  provide: APP_INITIALIZER,
  useFactory: init,
  deps: [SettingsService],
  multi: true
}

export function init(config: SettingsService) {
   return () => config.load_one();
}

//import declarations    
@Injectable()
export class SettingsService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  load_one(): Promise<boolean> {
    return new Promise<boolean>((resolve) => {
        this.http.get('url').subscribe(value => {
            console.log('loadSettings FINISH');
            resolve(true);
        });
    });
  }

  load_two(): Observable<any> {
    const promise = this.http.get('url');

    promise.subscribe(value => {
        console.log('loadSettings FINISH');
    });

    return promise;
  }
}
```

Somewhere in the app I have the function called `manageSettings()` (its code doesn't matter at the moment) which requires that the data from the `SettingsService` service is initialized.

And here's the thing - when I use the the function `load_two()`, the app does'nt wait until it completes:

```text
app-root constructor
manageSettings()
loadSettings FINISH
```

and when I use the function `load_one()` it works fine:

```text
loadSettings FINISH
app-root constructor
manageSettings()
```

can someone explain why that happens ?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

**Angular 12 added support for `Observable`s, so this should no longer be an issue if you're using Angular 12 or newer.**

The reason `load_one` works and `load_two` doesn't is that Angular 11 and older waits only for `Promise`s; not `Observable`s.

Here's the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.2.x/packages/core/src/application_init.ts#L66-L73):

> ```
> if (this.appInits) {
>     for (let i = 0; i < this.appInits.length; i++) {
>         const initResult = this.appInits[i]();
>         if (isPromise(initResult)) {
>             asyncInitPromises.push(initResult);
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```

Where [`isPromise`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/11.2.x/packages/core/src/util/lang.ts#L14-L18) is defined like this:

> ```
> export function isPromise<T = any>(obj: any): obj is Promise<T> {
>     // allow any Promise/A+ compliant thenable.
>     // It's up to the caller to ensure that obj.then conforms to the spec
>     return !!obj && typeof obj.then === 'function';
> }
> ```

Comment: Is there any difference between these two approaches? I mean the angular team hasn't deprecated the use of Promise over Observable yet. So, suppose if we are already using Promise then is there a reason that we should get change it to the Observable now?

Comment: @Himanshu There's no real reason to move to `Observable` if you're already using `Promise`. The change makes it more convenient to avoid a manual conversion from an existing `Observable` to a `Promise`. You can see for yourself in the [source](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/12.2.x/packages/core/src/application_init.ts#L129-L132), where Angular just converts the `Observable` into a `Promise` for you.